# theme of linux fedora

Tags: fedora, theme

[image]
[image]

It is how my windows look like in fedora. I want dark theme for better performance of my eyes. You know dark theme is better for eyes. So, I was searching in google "How to change theme of fedora?","dark theme of fedora". [Tweaking the look of Fedora Workstation with themes](https://fedoramagazine.org/tweaking-the-look-of-fedora-workstation-with-themes/), [Changing the Theme in GNOME](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/User_Guide/sect-User_Guide-Customizing_the_desktop-Changing_the_theme_.html). But, as far as I know if I change gnome-theme than, layout of fedora will be change. Like Top bar will display somewhere else or, it will be gone(I am not sure of fedora cause, I am new to fedora. I am saying that by `Kali Linux` which I had done on Kali Linux). So, is there any better way to change it to dark without doing anything with gnome....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install GNOME Tweak Tools (package `gnome-tweaks`) which allows some advanced GNOME configuration including changing themes. *Adwaita-dark* theme is available in the standard installation and it's just the default theme but dark.

[image: GNOME with Adwaita Dark theme]